# How to print before a while loop is started in Perl?

Tags: perl, printing, while-loop

I have this code in `Perl`:

```
print "Processing ... ";
while ( some condition ) {
    # do something over than 10 minutes
}
print "OK\n";
```

Now I get back the first print **after** the while loop is finished.

How can I print the messeage **before** the while loop is started?

Comment: See also the classic [Suffering from Buffering](https://www.plover.com/~mjd/perl/FAQs/Buffering.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Output is buffered, meaning the program decides when it actually renders what you `print`ed. You can put

```
$| = 1;
```

to flush `stdout` in this single instance. For more methods (auto-flushing, file flushing etc) you can search around SO for questions about this.

Comment: Nit: `$| = 1`; affects the handle returned by `select()`, not necessarily STDOUT. That said, `select()` returns STDOUT unless you've told it otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

Ordinarily, perl will buffer up to 8KB of output text before flushing it to the device, or up to the next newline if the device is a terminal. You can avoid this by adding

```
STDOUT->autoflush
```

to the top of your code, assuming that you are printing to `STDOUT`. This will force the data to be flushed after every `print`, `say` or `write` operation

Note that this is the same as using `$| = 1` but is significantly less cryptic and allows you to change the properties of any given file handle

Answer (score 0):

You can see the prints by flushing the buffers immediately after.

```
print "Processing ... ";
STDOUT->flush;
```

If you are using `autoflush`, you should save the current configuration by duplicating the file handle.

```
use autodie; # dies if error on open and close.

{
    STDOUT->flush; # empty its buffer
    open my $saved_stdout, '>&', \*STDOUT;
    STDOUT->autoflush;

    # ... output with autoflush active

    open STDOUT, '>&', $saved_stdout; # restore old STDOUT
}
```

See [`perldoc -f open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and search for `/\>\&/`